# Replicate mod-proxy behavior in IIS

Tags: iis, virtualhost

I need a http proxy server that redirects requests coming from mydomain.com to   http://localhost:8080
Apache web server does this with mod_procy and mod_proxy_http with the following configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.com
DocumentRoot D:/tmp/iis
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.jsp
<Proxy *>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

</VirtualHost>
```

My server is a windows machine and I’d like to use IIS (Internet Information Services) instead I tried the following IIS configuration:

binding

[image]

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRuleForReports" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(/.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8083/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

IIS rewrites the URL but doesn’t forward the request to another server as mod_proxy does in Apache

Is it possible to replicate Apache behavior in IIS? In that case what is the right server  configuration?

Comment: What is the error? "With no success" is a useless statement. BTW, make sure Mistake 3 is avoided, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: I tried to clarify my statement. I don’t have any errors but I’m not able to get out of IIS what I need

Comment: If you check examples around, you should see that no one uses `/` in the pattern. Other issues might occur once you fix this, but FRT is there to help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: with <match url="(.*)" /> it workes fine

Comment: Why don't you re-write your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a useful Apache proxy rule, you can import it into IIS. IIS will auto generate url rewrite rule. Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules).

[image]